# How to wait for all machine clients/requests to arrive and give an answer to all during startup/launching time? | Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I would like to implement something that resemble a temporary requests holder in the server side with Asp.Net Core but I have no idea from where should I start. This holder must wait for three distinguished http requests to arrive (by three distinguished clients). Upon receiving those three requests, the server/api will response to each one of those clients with a simple string and everything should be done during the startup time in client side.

From client perspective, it's quite a simple http request/response task with async/await. But from the server/api perspective I still did not figure it out. Any idea? Would socket be helpful here? ...

Note: This communications here are between machine to machine, no human/browser interaction. N(machine/clients)-to-1(machine/server)

Comment: What is meaning of "three distinguished" request ? Does it means that each client hit separate endpoint. Is there any order for request ? I think question needs for clarification.

Comment: Something like id that can differentiate each client from another ... They will hit the same endpoint and provide an input/message ... The server is suppose to wait for all the clients to join and combine all the inputs/messages into one and send it back to each joined client

Comment: ... and the order is not important here

Comment: You can indeed use websockets if you want to *push* the "all ready" message to the clients as soon as they've all checked in. Alternatively, you can use client *pull*. That is, have one "check-in" endpoint, and then have each client poll a separate "did everyone check in?" endpoint until that endpoint answers affirmatively. They are both widely used patterns, but pull tends to be simpler to implement.

Comment: As I understand, websocket is meant for two-way realtime (full duplex)  communication between browser and server. I seek m2m communication and persistence communication is not suitable for my scenario. Somehow, I managed to accomplish part of message assembly process with regular socket communication. But I still wondering about the main server getting shutdown for any reason. I discovered some interesting Pub/Sub protocols for IoT similar to RabbitMQ that could help me in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a very simple implementation. I would suggest a custom implementation:

1. Create a table on your database (Transactions with columns: ID,
   IsStep1Completed, IsStep2Completed, IsStep3Completed)
2. On each call you can update the table with each step
3. Everytime check
   if all
   three calls are completed

Now, this is an oversimplified implementation. You need also to make sure you cover these cases:

- What happens if one call fails? you want to drop the whole transaction?
- What happens if two calls are completed, but the third is taking a very long time. Do you want to set up a "time to live" transaction?
- If a call fails, Do you want to implement a rollback mechanism?
- What if the logic of your application  needs more/fewer calls as a transaction?

Comment: Database involvement would be a bit weird for me since the server machine is not  supposed to persist any data for this operation. A retrial mechanism would be helpful for the case you mentioned. I guess it would easier to implement it in client machine if the server machine took  more than 30sec. Since this operation will be executed in a private network I guess we are talking about ~1-2% for failure to occur.

Comment: You can also lookup Redis Cache if you don't want to involve db

Comment: Redis is a distributed cache which you'll have to install. If you are sure you'll only be running a single server, you might be [able to use the built-in memory cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory) instead. I think you'll find you can't get away from persisting these statuses to some kind of server cache or DB, though. Hopefully you only meant you're not supposed to persist anything *to disk*.